# I can't modify a scope inside a function

Tags: angularjs

when I get the result from my http request , I want to modify a scope  . To test, I tried to display the scope before making the http request and after its success :

```
$scope.CopyFiles=function(destination){
  for(var i=0; i<$scope.list.length; i++){
    console.log("test 1 "+$scope.list[i]);

    var response=$http({method: 'GET', url:      
             '/checkIsSubdir/'+$scope.list[i]+'/'+destination});

    response.success(function(result) {
      console.log("check"+result.data);
      console.log("test 2 "+$scope.list[i]);
    });
    response.error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
      console.log("checksubdir oops");
    });
  };
```

my http request has succeded since it displayed my `result.data`.

my problem is that the first  `console.log("test 1 "+$scope.list[i]);` displays the scope but 
`console.log("test 2 "+$scope.list[i]);` displays **undefined**

how to do to fix this ?

Answer (score 1):

Simply your code is executing asynchronously inside a for loop.

That is because your for loop makes an ajax call & end when the value doesn't satisfied for loop condition at that time the value of `i` would be +1 than `$scope.list.length`, so thats why you are getting `$scope.list[i]` value undefined.

In this case use of `angular.forEach` would solve your problem, here the index value is available at that for loop success

```
angular.forEach($scope.list, function(value, index){
    console.log("test 1 "+$scope.list[index]);

    var response=$http({method: 'GET', url:      
             '/checkIsSubdir/'+$scope.list[index]+'/'+destination});

    response.success(function(result) {
      console.log("check"+result.data);
      console.log("test 2 "+$scope.list[index]);
    });
    response.error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
      console.log("checksubdir oops");
    });
});
```

Comment: I've changed it but I still have the same problem

Comment: could you create an plunkr for the same?

Comment: no I can't since I'm using local webservice

Comment: @marwa I will add it plunkr or fiddle afterwards..could you share your `$scope.list` data

Comment: my $scope.list  is for example : [2,3,7]

Comment: I've found the answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17256513/angularjs-loop-post-requests-and-pass-each-index-into-related-response)  !!!!! thank you for your time