# Angularjs for-loop counter in $http service

Tags: angularjs, http, for-loop, service

I am using the below for loop in angular. My problem is that the forItr counter is reflected as being increased after using the $http Service.

Code:

```
var app = angular.module('noviceApp', []);
app.controller('noviceAppController', ['$scope', '$http', function ($scope, $http) {

var iterations = 1;

    $scope.myFunction = function() {  
        for(var forItr = 0; forItr < iterations; forItr++) { 
            var params = {};   
            params.testStr = forItr; 
            console.log("foritr before post: " + forItr);  
            $http.get('http://localhost:9200/_stats/index,store')  
                .success(function(data, status) {
                console.log("foritr after post: " + forItr);   
            }); 
        } 
    }
}]);
```

the log:
foritr before post: 0
foritr after post: 1

How does forItr become "1" if it hasn't completed the for loop? And is there anyway to reference the for loop value of the counter?

Many thanks

Comment: `$http` is an asynchronous call, meaning your code will continue to run before the success function has a chance to fire.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [AngularJS: loop POST requests and pass each index into related response](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17256513/angularjs-loop-post-requests-and-pass-each-index-into-related-response)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because it's being updated before the $http is finished, you can wrap it in a closure to solve this:

```
var app = angular.module('noviceApp', []);
app.controller('noviceAppController', ['$scope', '$http', function ($scope, $http) {

var iterations = 1;

    $scope.myFunction = function() {  
        for(var forItr = 0; forItr < iterations; forItr++) { 
            (function(forItr){
                var params = {};   
                params.testStr = forItr; 
                console.log("foritr before post: " + forItr);  
                $http.get('http://localhost:9200/_stats/index,store')  
                    .success(function(data, status) {
                    console.log("foritr after post: " + forItr);   
                });                 
            })(forItr);
        } 
    }
}]);
```

Comment: This is a pretty elegant answer. I'm impressed.

Comment: Thank you (everyone) for your help. I had to lookup what closures are (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Closures) and now I know. Sorry for the delay.

Comment: Works as expected. Thank You :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to use some closure function that would have its value until the function ends. You could do it in Angular Way by replacing `foreach` with `angular.forEach` which creates own function and in that function value & index will be available always

**Code**

```
angular.forEach(iterations, function(value, index){
       var params = {};   
       params.testStr = index; 
       console.log("Index before post: " + index);  
       $http.get('http://localhost:9200/_stats/index,store')  
       .success(function(data, status) {
          console.log("Index after post: " + index);   
       }); 
});
```